# Look up argument types based on previous argument value, also return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to give a *generic* type to a function, so that it will return a type I have specified in the *generic* type.
The second argument should also be looked up from events...

What I'm trying to do:
`listen<MenuChannels>('menu','1') // Should return type '3'`

Function:

```
listen<T extends WebsocketChannel[]>(
    name: T[number]['channel'],
    event: T[number]['events'][number]['name'], // Doesnt work atm
  ): Observable<any> { // Doesnt work atm
}
```

Types:

```
export type MenuChannels = [
  {
    channel: 'menu'
    events: Menu1Events
  },
  {
    channel: 'menu-2'
    events: Menu2Events
  },
]

export type Menu1Events = [
  {
    name: '1'
    value: '3'
  },
  {
    name: '2'
    value: '4'
  },
]

export type Menu2Events = [
  {
    name: '5'
    value: '7'
  },
  {
    name: '6'
    value: '8'
  },
]
```

```
export interface WebsocketChannel {
  channel: string
  events: Event[]
}

interface Event {
  name: string
  value: any
}
```

Comment: You can't do this as stated because the function still needs to be generic after you specify `T` and [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) has not been implemented. If you can stand a little indirection you can do it as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE2KvN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The playground solution is kind of confusing for me, but it works. Thanks.
Sad that the github suggestion isn't implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to call `listen<MenuChannels>(⋯)` and have the return type still depend on the types of its inputs (so that, e.g., `listen<MenuChannels>('menu', '1')` is of type `"3"` while `listen<MenuChannels>('menu-2', '5')` is of type `"5"`).  That means that you want `listen<MenuChannels>` to still be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), so that the compiler can infer a generic type arguments `K1` and `K2` for the `name` and `event` inputs and use it to compute the return type.

But you can't do that in TypeScript currently.  TypeScript lacks so-called *partial type argument inference* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). Right now, if you have a generic function like `listen()` and you manually specify a type argument like `listen<MenuChannels>(⋯)`, then you have to manually specify *all* the type arguments. You can't just specify `T` and let the compiler infer `K1` and `K2`. Conversely, if you want inference you need to let the compiler infer *all* of the type arguments, including `T`. Type argument inference is all or nothing.

Until and unless partial type argument inference is implemented, you'll need to work around it.  The standard workaround is to use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) as indirection, so that `listen<MenuChannels>()` returns another generic function, and that function can infer `K1` and `K2` for you.  It would be of the following form:

```
declare function listen<T extends WebsocketChannel[]>():
  <K1 extends ???, K2 extends ???>
    (name: K1, event: K2) => ???;
```

And you would call it like this:

```
listen<MenuChannels>()('menu', '1')
```

or if you're likely to use `listen<MenuChannels>` a lot, you could write:

```
const listenMenuChannels = listen<MenuChannels>();
listenMenuChannels('menu', '1');    
listenMenuChannels('menu-2', '5');
```

Assuming that's okay, we can proceed.

---

In order to make this more straightforward, it will be helpful to transform `T extends WebsocketChannel[]` into an object type where you can just [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with `K1` and `K2` to get the desired return type.  I'll write a utility type called `WebsocketChannelLookup<T>` with the intent that you get the following output for `MenuChannels`:

```
type WebsocketChannelLookupMenuChannels =
  WebsocketChannelLookup<MenuChannels>;
/* type WebsocketChannelLookupMenuChannels = {
    menu: {
        1: "3";
        2: "4";
    };
    "menu-2": {
        5: "7";
        6: "8";
    };
} */
```

With that type, you can see how `listen<MenuChannels>()('menu', '1')` corresponds to `WebsocketChannelLookupMenuChannels["menu"]["1"]`.

Here's the utility type implementation:

```
type WebsocketChannelLookup<T extends WebsocketChannel[]> = {
  [U in T[number] as U['channel']]: {
    [E in U['events'][number] as E['name']]:
    E['value']
  }
}
```

This uses [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of  array member types (`T[number]` is the element type of the `T` array because if you index into an array with a numeric index, you get an element).  We use the `channel` member as the key, and for the value we similarly iterate over the elements of the `events` member to get the value.

---

Armed with that, now `listen()` looks like:

```
declare function listen<T extends WebsocketChannel[]>():
  <K1 extends keyof WebsocketChannelLookup<T>, K2 extends keyof WebsocketChannelLookup<T>[K1]>
    (name: K1, event: K2) => WebsocketChannelLookup<T>[K1][K2];
```

So we take `T`, transform it to `WebsocketChannelLookup<T>`, and do nested indexes into that.

Let's test it out:

```
const listenMenuChannels = listen<MenuChannels>();
const x = listenMenuChannels('menu', '1');
//    ^? const x: "3"
const y = listenMenuChannels('menu-2', '5')
//    ^? const y: "7"
```

Looks good. This is the behavior you want (as long as you're okay with the extra indirection required due to the lack of microsoft/TypeScript#26242).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwiwGcMRUAeAFXhAA9TVgj4B1EAIyJzAGsQMAwgAsoqVCAgBtALoA+ABQBKAFwBYAFDx45ANIBGGvTJN4fAJ45ErDl179ho8RAAyOHD2QAHKrIA08HQAmQwYTc0trTm4+QRExCVd3Lx9JfTkNLS15VCgAWxBlAL1-EAA3MgxCoMV4AF5ZSNsYh3iXNw9vSllUvWlUwOkAbg0NDDNPBDYou1jHBPbk6jpQ5imm+zinGQba+ABvDPhJAFV4LHxKSVRkXPYQGGl4KGZjyQByME2JN+lpQoPNJlJABRM74V5vMoVIg-K43O4PJ7MYHvHL5H5-Q5aFFvUpQCDIEA-Q4AXw0ZPUo3Gkxs0Q2czaSU8AFkyMgWk5mLVDms6bNWokOuRWdcORIiLJhuoAPQAKngYwmjT5YsZHRF7K+EC5+yx8Hy13+esy8D0hQARABmc1Sk0mwIWgAsNr1JNtmXNBuQAFpAuajYC7fAAKwWgDsLsDdoAbBaAByRk1u8nwWXSkbqMB4EgEYgMDWqnWEEhkYVswsKRRSrOoHO0Oq5kuoAtaojyN5et7+N56N5VjTS6UmgB6AH4NDWc2YG8X8+XW+2vb6u-A3sG+1LByPx5Tdxo6J4cDAMArqfAWwydZJDgCTZ8GYUO2y3nqoagMERChq9MDyu+iKSvg3nq96tI+S6BC+UZvh+X5soEv7QoBGjSBmB5HieioIN+iH-g216AremRogUq69nqeIEqRbyWlBWgkkBhF6iRj6QRR+KEo+jp0fADEoWhtCHsep5KhqCF-h++HAVGLGruu7FUY+YY8XxTEyXk1HRjxWiUZxq5xipjGobu6HCecpAwIgUBgDS0zNFquqAqBTiFCQMDnAA5ocMGfvAuEYDI5IZuZ9xWTZfkSY5WiyW5nmHLppGiGYQXqEAA)